# i cant access to post data in get from django

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

I need read 'dataset' in get function for showing amount and name in the template but I can't access to 'dataset' in get function

class Port(View):

```
def post(self, request, pid):

    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get("http://localhost:8001/pay/" + str(pid))

    if response.status_code is 200:
        try:
            dataset = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
            print("@@@",data['amount'],' - ',data['name'],' - ',pid)
            return dataset

        except ConnectionError as ce:
            print(ce)
            return HttpResponse("Json Parse Error")
        return dataset

    else:
        return HttpResponse("* wrong request *")

def get(self, request, pid):
    
    context = {
        'amount'    : dataset['amount'],
        'firstname' : dataset['name'],
        'order_id'  : pid,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe dataset is initialized as an attribute in Port class. Use `self.dataset`